# scss individual partials not updating changes in live server

Tags: css, sass

Live server does not show changes made and saved in the individual .scss files but those changes are made to the css.style.css.

The expected outcome is every time I add code to those individual files ex. (_header.scss) it would reflect in the live server showing in real time those changes made *like changing the background color, but nothing happens.*

I'm fairly new to coding and am moving over from wordpress themes to using Visual studio code.

Have Windows 10 operating system with node sass for windows running with npm

I have tried Chrome, Shift+F5 refreshes and clears the cache and still no difference.

My file setup is a folder on my desktop with an html file, CSS folder/style.css and images folder

Have Sass folder in project with _base.scss for fonts and variables etc.

```
 - main.scss file for the @imports
 - _header.scss
 - _navbar.scss
 - _services.scss for a services section on the website
 - _typoghraphy.scss
```

and other similar files

in json file have

```js
        "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css-style.css -w",
     "devserver": "live-server --browser=firefox",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css output-style compressed",
        "build": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
```

in the individual scss files for example i have this

```css
    .header {
    background-color: $color-secondary;
     }
```

but color does not show just words from the html

Could There must be a problem with CSS linking path? How do i make sure am linking new CSS files that are generated from your scss

Comment: Guessing you're running the `start` script? Irrespective, IIRC you have to restart your script if you add a new file, however, changes to any existing `.scss` files should work and reflect in your site.

You may also want to get rid of the `--browser` flag in your `devserver` script.

Comment: do you mean in the cmd write npm start?

Comment: Yes. In your terminal write `npm run start`

Comment: just did and no changes

Comment: @pai.not.pi `npm run start ` solved my problem. Can you explain why that made a difference? I'd been using `npm run compile:sass` when the problem occurred. Someone on here recommended removing a cache file, but there isn't one. Thanks!